# Gnome Shell font problem

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I am using Gnome-shell for the first time and am liking the speed of the DE.

There's a UI glitch which is annoying. When typing certain letters I get others. This is also true of certain UI text elements like the following example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After some searching of the web, I found that most visual elements in Gnome Shell are to be found in the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css` file.

Opening it I realised it is using the Cantarell font which was not installed. I downloaded it from the web and installed it (by copying the ttf files in `~/.fonts`) and the problem was gone.